# How to limit select edge loops on seam?

Tags: mesh, scripting, edit-mode, edges, loop

Basically select edge loops will result like this:
[image]

Is there any way (or script) to limit the select loop on seam quickly?
so the result should be like this:
[image]

EDIT:

Bellow is example selection what i mean,
its on rizomUV, so its to do possible in blender at least through script?
[image]

Comment: Select the to edge by clicking on it and ctrl+click on the bottom edge. Blender will select every edge between them (in shortest path)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
i already know "Pick Shortest Path" selection,
but this is not what i want. i need to select limit loop on seam quickly like in rizomUV loops selection, if it possible in blender

Comment: How about selecting all seams, ripping them (V key) then selecting your edges, doing whatever you want, then merging the ripped vertices again? Would that workflow work for you?

Comment: Easiest way to stop an edge loop selection is, hide what you don't want selected.  Could select linked, limited by seam, hide all but selected, select edge loop if your seams only ever delineate islands.  If unwrapped (and what else are seams for), you could enable select linked on UV editor and select a loop there, but it doesn't act the same way in case of tris.  I don't think there's a great way to do what you want, no simple algorithm, but I also think the various ways of handling this that aren't great, are still plenty good enough.  The only time they aren't, you have too many polys.

Comment: Wait, it does handle tris the same way (I just had seamed tris.)  So maybe that's your solution, linked UV editor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in standard Blender or any add-on I know of. Writing such a script could certainly be done.

A useful workaround might be to put the faces in top and bottom areas into a Face Map. Select the edge loop, then click Deselect for the Face Map. You can select the top and bottom areas easily by selecting one face from both, pressing ctrl-L, and selecting Seam in Delimit.